# Is this "debate" a noun or a verb?

Tags: verbs, nouns, prepositions, parts-of-speech

Monday's vote opens the floor to **debate** on the bill and the Senate is expected to schedule a full vote by week's end.

Comment: *Monday's vote opens the floor, to debate on the bill, and the Senate is expected to schedule a full vote by week's end.* The commas help visualize a different scenario.

Comment: *Monday's vote opens the floor to **a/the** debate on the bill and the Senate is expected to schedule a full vote by week's end.*

Answer (score 1):

It is a noun. You could just as easily say

> Monday's vote opens the floor *for* debate on the bill and the Senate is expected to schedule a full vote by week's end.

or

> Monday's vote opens the floor to *discussion* on the bill and the Senate is expected to schedule a full vote by week's end.

In the original sentence, *debate* is the object of the preposition *to*, not an infinitive.

Comment: I see. Thank you. And is this sentence implying that the Senate will vote later than this weekend?

Comment: It depends on when *Monday* is. If Monday is in the future, it is still Sunday or earlier, and the vote is by next Friday, after this weekend, but before next. If Monday is in the past, there should be no weekend between now and the vote.

Comment: This "monday" is this week's. So the Senate will decide when to vote by this weekend and actually vote sometime later than that?

Comment: Only if the context allows. The statement could as well have appeared in a context where the word *debate* happens to be a verb instead. Think of it. And what about that word with an article prefacing it?

Comment: @Kris I agree the sentence could have been restructured so that *to debate* was an infinitive, such as *Monday's vote opens the floor to debate the bill ...*. And, with an article it would have been more obviously a noun.